# Use paddingBottom for all TextView based on font size

Tags: android, fonts, textview

I use in my application a custom font called Barlow. However, I need to specify a `bottomPadding` in each `TextView` because the font isn't centered vertically.
Here's what I did:

```xml
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/Widget.Comblat.TextView</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceBody1">@style/TextAppearance.Comblat.Body1</item>
    <item name="textAppearanceHeadline3">@style/TextAppearance.Comblat.H3</item>
    ...
</style>

<!-- TextView -->
<style name="Widget.Comblat.TextView" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextView">
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">1.6dp</item>
</style>

<!-- CustomFont -->
<style name="TextAppearance.Comblat.Body1" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body1">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/mbarlow_condensed_regular</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:letterSpacing">0</item>
    <item name="android:includeFontPadding">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorDarkPrimary60</item>
</style>


<style name="TextAppearance.Comblat.H3" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline3">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/mbarlow_condensed_semibold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorDarkPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">48sp</item>
    <item name="android:includeFontPadding">false</item>
    <item name="android:letterSpacing">-0.023</item>
</style>
```

Here I set `paddingBottom` to `1.6dp`. But this is working only on the Body1 font (my formula for `paddingBottom` is `0.1*font_size`), for H3 I would like to set `4.8dp`.

Is there a way to set a `paddingBottom` for all TextView but depending on the font size ? I supposed it is possible programmatically, or by Overriding the TextView.
Of course I could set a custom style on each TextView in my layouts, but hey, I'm lazy guys

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I created a custom TextView, and replace all TextView with my own.

Here's the code:

```java
public class BarlowTextView extends MaterialTextView {
    public static final float RATIO_FONT_PADDING = 0.1f;
    private int dpAsPixels = 0;

    public BarlowTextView(@NonNull Context context) {
        super(context);
        float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        dpAsPixels = (int) (getTextSize() * scale * RATIO_FONT_PADDING);
    }

    public BarlowTextView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        dpAsPixels = (int) (getTextSize() * scale * RATIO_FONT_PADDING);
    }

    public BarlowTextView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        dpAsPixels = (int) (getTextSize() * scale * RATIO_FONT_PADDING);
    }

    public BarlowTextView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        dpAsPixels = (int) (getTextSize() * scale * RATIO_FONT_PADDING);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        setPaddingRelative(0 , 0 , 0 , dpAsPixels);
    }
}
```